# Noether's definition of right and left ideals?

Tags: math-history

could anyone provide me with Emmy Noether's definition of right and left ideals? The German original and references would be welcome.

I am assuming she was the one who first coined those two kinds of one-sided ideals, though the term ideal was already in use in Dedekind. But maybe my assumption is wrong. Feel free to correct me if necessary.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you expect to learn from it?

Comment: I would like to see how she formulates it in German, some nuances....I am curious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know when or by whom they were first introduced, but Noether deals with them in her paper *Hyperkomplexe Größen und Darstellungstheorie*, Mathematische Zeitschrift $30$ $(1929)$, $641$-$692$, available [here](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002371448). On p. $646$, the second page of the first chapter, we find the following:

> $3$. $\mathfrak{G}$ sei ein Ring, d. h. eine Abelsche Gruppe gegenüber Addition, wo auch eine Multiplikation definiert ist, mit den Eigenschaften
>
> $$\begin{align*}
> r(a+b)&=ra+rb\\
> (a+b)r&=ar+br\\
> ab\cdot c&=a\cdot bc\;.
> \end{align*}$$
>
> Jedes Element $r$ definiert zugleich zwei Operatoren: die Operatoren $rx$ und $xr$. Zugelassene Untergruppen sind die „Ideale“ $\mathfrak{a}$, und zwar:
>
> - *linksseitige*, die die Operationen $rx$ gestatten: $r\mathfrak{a}\subseteqq\mathfrak{a}$;
> - *rechtsseitige*, die die Operationen $xr$ gestatten: $\mathfrak{a}r\subseteqq\mathfrak{a}$;
> - *zweiseitige*, die beide Operationen gestatten.

This terminology can still be seen, as in [this article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_%C3%BCber_einem_K%C3%B6rper) in German Wikipedia, though I have the impression that *Linksideal* and *Rechtsideal* are now more common.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read somewhere that she introduced them in a paper from 1921"Idealtheorie in Ringbereichen" [The Theory of Ideals in Ring Domains], Mathematische Annalen 83 (1). I have also found these other two titles prior to the paper you mention:(1923), "Eliminationstheorie und allgemeine Idealtheorie", Mathematische Annalen  90 (3–4): 229–61,doi:10.1007/BF01455443.
(1924), "Eliminationstheorie und Idealtheorie", Jahresbericht der Deutschen Mathematiker-Vereinigung 33: 116–20. Any idea whether she defines them there?

Comment: @Javier: You’re welcome. I took a quick look at the $1921$ paper and saw only commutative rings, but I admit that I didn’t read it carefully.

Comment: M-Scott. Ok, thanks. So I guess the 1926 paper can be the one referenced.

Comment: @Javier: I just took a quick look at the $1923$ and $1924$ papers and didn’t notice any one-sided ideals there, either.

Comment: M.Scott. Thanks for your useful info.I will open some other thread on related issues in a while, which migh be interesting for you. Just watch out :)

Comment: @Javier: Will do. You’re welcome!

Comment: There you have: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289276/a-question-on-join-homomorphism-and-ideals

Comment: I have just found this statement in some page: "Noether's groundbreaking work in algebra began in 1920. In collaboration with W. Schmeidler, she then published a paper about the theory of ideals in which they defined left and right ideals in a ring." Which paper was that? From which exact year? Can anyne provide the definitions they give there, in the original form and language? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently, those definitions were already here: E. No­eth­er and W. Schmeidler: “Mod­uln in nichtkom­mut­at­iven Bereichen, ins­beson­dere aus Dif­fer­en­tial- und Dif­fer­en­zenaus­drück­en” [Mod­ules in non-com­mut­at­ive do­mains, es­pe­cially those com­posed of dif­fer­en­tial and dif­fer­ence ex­pres­sions], Math. Z. 8 : 1–​2 (1920), pp. 1–​35. Any referenceor quotation? That paper seems to be a reprint of another from 1918 in the same Journal with the same Title and the same pagination. Any explanation from Historians here?