# Relation between Noether's one-sided ideals and Polish notation?

Tags: ideals, math-history

Given the definitions of one-sided ideals (right ideals; left ideals) bu Emmy Noether, as referred in this answer [Noether's definition of right and left ideals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288450/noethers-definition-of-right-and-left-ideals/1288919?noredirect=1#comment2617687_1288919), I would like to raise the following question (I hope it is not far off the target): Is there any relation to Polish (and reverse Polish) notation? Somehow it seems like prefix, postfix to me.......

Prefix notation:    + 2    5

Postfix notation:   2    5 +

Infix notation:      2  +  5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no relation with Polish notation. In fact, Polish notation makes the relationship more obscure: the difference in question is between $r \, a \, b \, {+} \, {\times}$ and $a \, b \, {+} \, r \, {\times}$.

Comment: What a strange question...

Comment: Well, It seemed to me that the difference  rx versus xr was pretty much a notational difference, depending on whether you have the operator on the right or on the left......Am I wrong?

Comment: What I am trying to say is the following. Noether clearly states Jedes Element r definiert zugleich zwei Operatoren: die Operatoren rx und xr. Every element r defines at the same time two operators, rx and xr. Two operators. It is obvious that in the above examples from Polish notation we only have one, and it is a matter of convention where we place it. So far so good. But, my question is: Noether is clearly mentioning the product operation as operator....But product is commutative......Your may say the ring is not conmutative, but that should be the consequence, not the premise, right?

Comment: @HansLundmark Indeed... this user has exhibited this pattern of conflating structures with notations in at least two other questions. I think it's actually a fairly common misperception of the two things. (Or maybe a language difference we haven't worked out yet.)

Comment: @rschwieb Well, as it happens, the so-called operator precedence grammar which some linguists use to account for what they interpret as right ideals, seems to have a lot in common with some of the version of Polish notation......So I might be more right than one might think....